# Using C# API, is it possible to get all rows assigned to a particular user?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

We are trying to build an interface which rolls up tasks across all sheets. So I was attempting to use the Search method, using the Name or email address as the query, then iterate through the result checking if SearchObjectType is ROW. I do get results, but they are not complete. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
string query = "name@domain.org";
IList<SearchResultItem> results = smartsheet.SearchResources.Search(query).Results;
foreach (SearchResultItem result in results)
{
    if (result.ObjectType == SearchObjectType.ROW)
    {
        Sheet thisSheet = smartsheet.SheetResources.GetSheet(result.ParentObjectId.Value, new SheetLevelInclusion[] { SheetLevelInclusion.ROW_PERMALINK }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        Row row = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.GetRow(result.ParentObjectId.Value, result.ObjectId.Value, new RowInclusion[] { RowInclusion.COLUMNS, RowInclusion.ROW_PERMALINK, RowInclusion.COLUMN_TYPE, RowInclusion.FORMAT }, null);
        string rowData = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Sheet info: " + thisSheet.Name + " " + thisSheet.Permalink);

        foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            rowData += cell.DisplayValue + ",";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(rowData);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be best to add a short example of the code you're currently using here to give people a better chance of understanding your problem and getting you a solution.

Comment: What exactly is not complete? Do you not receive particular rows that you expected or is some information about the row missing?

Comment: I think that I figured out why I wasn't getting full results. Apparently the person who provided me with the API key does not have access to all sheets. The question remains on whether there is a better way to roll up project tasks from all sheets.